# Google Sheets SUMIFS formula with condition of values in range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to fill table with sum of values from dataset with 3 conditions:

1. Month
2. Ad Format
3. Agencies being in the key list

here's the example
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MC3rdBEUCelFBjWNGaMA-Y2tHo4JdReBDuJasTOPgtI/edit?usp=sharing

my formula (red fill cell) not working somehow. I did check all web search results and didn't get the right answer what is incorrect. so help is much appreciated

Comment: Your sheet is not accessible. Please edit permission and give edit access.

Comment: sorry for that and done)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear all the cells of existing formulas within the cells of `C5:N12` and enter this formula in `Cell C5`

```
=let(Σ,filter(B22:E,xmatch(C22:C,tocol(G22:G,1))),
       makearray(counta(B5:B12),12,lambda(r,c,let(Δ,sum(ifna(filter(index(Σ,,4),index(Σ,,1)=index(C3:N3,,c),index(Σ,,3)=index(B5:B12,r)))),if(Δ>0,Δ,)))))
```

[image]

Comment: holy molly! I didn't expect that to be so complicated. Thank you so much! Btw, is there any option to make it easier with using only standard formulas like in my example?

Comment: and one more question - which part is responsible for Format check? Can't get it. Sadly had to use data from other sheets and facing problem to match all the ranges

Comment: Sorry whats a `format check`?!

Comment: column D in dataset to match values in B5:B12

Comment: oh, i get it. It's the first range of B22:E. But looks like i'm doing something wrong cause formula isn't working when i'm trying to change ranges here filter(B22:E,xmatch(C22:C,tocol(G22:G,1))) for other ones from few other sheets